# JavaFX - ImageView - Why isn't this image rendering?

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

```
ImageView starterImage = new ImageView(new Image("file:Fallen.png"));
root.getChildren().add(starterImage);
```

That's just a snip from a larger file. Why isn't it appearing? The program runs in NetBeans without any errors at all, and all the other nodes are showing up except for the image.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `getResource()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27047819/230513).

Comment: The image is located in the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an Image in the project that you want it to work even if you export your project as a jar file.

Let's say that your image is in the resource folder(resources) and under the package images(recommended way).

```
Image image = new Image(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/images/flower.png");
```

If your image is in the same package as your java file:

```
Image image = new Image(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/flower.png");
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) are all the ways you can load an `Image` (URL,FILE,CLASSPATH)